# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'). Codewars task

Tags: javascript

I write solutions to tasks and got

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length').

This is my solution

```
function sumArray(array) {
  if (array === null || array.length < 2) {
    return 0;
  }
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  return sum - Math.max(...array) - Math.min(...array)
}
```

Could you help me find an error in my code?

Comment: this involves calling the function `sumArray` please provide information

Comment: You must have provided an invalid argument (not an array in this case) to your sumArray function, give the code that uses it please.

Comment: `array` is `undefined` - that's the problem. What needs to happen in that case is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined` is not `===` with `null`. You need to test for both before calling `length` on your argument, or don't call this method with an `undefined` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check is array even defined and that it is type array.

And I think you need to return 0 in all variant where argument array is not defined or null

```
if (!array || (Array.isArray(array) && array.length < 2)) {
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it's possible that the error is being caused by calling the `sumArray` function with an undefined or null value as its argument. The code below is fixed.

```
function sumArray(array) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length < 2) {
    return 0;
  }
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  return sum - Math.max(...array) - Math.min(...array);
}
```